# Spanish idiom for "I was afraid you would say/do that"

Tags: españa

Is there a better translation for "I was afraid you would say/do that," than "Tenía miedo de que dijeras eso", to express resignation or acceptance of an event?

> "I'm sorry, but she is in love with someone else"
>
> "I was afraid you would say that."

Answer (score 4):

Creo que podría ser un "me lo temía".

Answer (score 2):

In Argentina (and I guess in some other countries too) we could also say:

- Me lo / la venía venir. (I saw it coming.)

Either "lo" or "la" can be used, but I think "la" may be more usual. The pronoun "lo" means "it", whatever "it" is. The pronoun "la", which is used in some other idioms, in this case means "la situación" (feminine), i.e. "the situation".

Another idiom that comes to mind where "la" (not "lo") is used, but which has nothing to do with the idiom at issue, is:

- Me la estás haciendo difícil. (You are making things difficult for me.)

In this other (also unrelated) idiom, either "lo" or "la" can be used:

- Lo / La pasé bien. (I had a good time.)

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista la mejor traducción para;

"*I'm sorry, but she is in love with someone else*"

"*I was afraid you would say that*."

---

sería;

*Lo siento, pero ella esta enamorada de otro*.

**Temía que dijeras eso.**